# Linear mixed model - list error

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement a linear mixed model using the following code. is.ill is a binary response variable and I'm trying to predict this for each gene in my dataset.

```
for (gene in 1:122) {
nlme.m1 <- lme(is.ill ~ pulse + age + gender + data[,gene], random = ~1|pulse)
lmm_analysis = summary(nlme.m1)
}
```

However this code fails right now due to the error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~is.ill + pulse +  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'data'
```

data is 331 x 122 but I can't see what the problem is?

Here's the output of:

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   331 obs. of  122 variables:
 $ A0000004: num  0.616 0.543 0.486 0.326 0.378 ...
 $ A0000005: num  1.96 2.05 1.98 1.94 2 ...
 $ A0000007: num  0.659 0.588 0.769 0.628 0.464 ...
 $ A0000002: num  0.1761 0.0864 0.1492 0.1673 0.2455 ...
 $ A0000008: num  0.185 0.117 0.79 0.117 0.117 ...
 $ A0000010: num  0.143 0.49 0.49 0.587 0.243 ...
 $ A0000011: num  2.2 1.5 1.34 1.27 1.77 ...
 $ A0000013: num  -0.25 -0.304 -0.467 -0.372 -0.544 ...
 $ A0000018: num  2.16 2.06 1.97 1.99 1.87 ...
 $ A0000021: num  2.19 2.27 2.28 2.26 2.48 ...
 $ A0000022: num  1.068 0.958 1.049 0.966 1.061 ...
 $ A0000023: num  0.3945 0.0414 0.1072 0.0607 0.1367 ...
 $ A0000025: num  1.111 1.111 1.401 0.831 0.799 ...
 $ A0000027: num  1.44 1.36 1.47 1.29 1.56 ...
 $ A0000030: num  0.0569 -0.1107 0.0755 -0.0964 0.1875 ...
 $ A0000032: num  0.155 0.267 0.885 0.713 0.769 ...
 $ A0000035: num  0.0828 -0.2596 -0.068 -0.1244 0.0607 ...
 $ A0000036: num  0.4654 0.0294 0.1139 -0.1379 0.4281 ...
 $ A0000038: num  -0.762 -0.595 -0.332 -0.374 -0.165 ...
 $ A0000039: num  0.415 1.955 1.314 2.049 0.415 ...
 $ A0000040: num  -1.248 -0.73 -0.62 -0.662 -0.917 ...
 $ A0000043: num  2.08 1.99 2.07 2.12 2.16 ...
 $ A0000045: num  0.999 -0.833 -0.699 -0.907 -0.327 ...
 $ A0000046: num  0.615 0.592 0.674 0.539 0.58 ...
 $ A0000048: num  2.32 2.04 2.46 2.02 2.36 ...
 $ A0000050: num  0.4409 0.2625 0.3139 0.0607 0.238 ...
 $ A0000052: num  1.71 1.66 1.94 1.8 1.92 ...
 $ A0000053: num  2.24 2.08 2.08 2.03 2.16 ...
 $ A0000059: num  -0.804 -0.804 -0.804 -0.804 -0.804 ...
 $ A0000060: num  2.48 2.69 2.67 2.55 2.57 ...
 $ A0000061: num  0.712 0.539 0.697 0.624 0.79 ...
 $ A0000062: num  1.52 1.34 1.29 1.23 1.26 ...
 $ A0000064: num  0.961 1.654 1.425 1.477 2.121 ...
 $ A0000065: num  1.61 1.94 1.8 1.47 1.61 ...
 $ A0000067: num  -1.85 -1.93 -2.04 -1.93 -2.24 ...
 $ A0000068: num  -0.64 -0.352 -0.228 -0.147 -0.314 ...
 $ A0000069: num  1.146 0.822 1.265 1.173 1.021 ...
 $ A0000070: num  -0.58 -0.839 0.173 0.983 -0.475 ...
 $ A0000074: num  2.92 2.53 3.26 2.55 2.78 ...
 $ A0000075: num  -0.0306 0.0492 0.1139 0.0492 0.2201 ...
 $ A0000076: num  -0.368 -0.62 -0.194 -0.387 0.1 ...
 $ A0000077: num  1.83 1.87 1.63 1.83 3.13 ...
 $ A0000078: num  0.863 0.604 0.814 0.362 0.819 ...
 $ A0000079: num  0.477 0.204 0.554 0.767 0.617 ...
 $ A0000082: num  2.1 2.04 2.05 2.1 2.18 ...
 $ A0000084: num  0.3598 0.3243 0.1553 0.2553 0.0453 ...
 $ A0000085: num  2.33 2.3 1.65 2.24 1.14 ...
 $ A0000086: num  1.62 1.65 1.53 1.78 1.21 ...
 $ A0000088: num  0.276 0.236 0.19 0.124 0.204 ...
 $ A0000091: num  1.12 1.03 1.31 1.12 1.16 ...
 $ A0000094: num  1.73 1.84 1.8 1.73 1.69 ...
 $ A0000095: num  1.72 2.05 2.01 2.02 1.77 ...
 $ A0000096: num  -0.0395 -0.1463 -0.1062 -0.1463 -0.1931 ...
 $ A0000097: num  2.82 2.38 2.48 2.48 2.4 ...
 $ A0000100: num  2.42 2.18 2.16 2.21 2.39 ...
```

etc

Comment: a reproducible example http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 would be nice.  Could we at least see the results of `str(data)` please?

Comment: Just a side note: even if `lme` works, this line `lmm_analysis = summary(nlme.m1)` will be overwritten and you will have result only for the last gene. Use `apply` instead of loop.

Comment: I've included results of str(data). 

Thanks for the tip about apply! Just need to try and get lme to work now!

Answer (score 1):

In general R 'prefers' it if all the data for a model are included within the same data frame.  Different packages vary in how fussy they are about this -- I think your approach *might* work with `lm`, for example -- but it looks like `lme` is a bit fussier. Here's an approach that might work:

Make up some testing data:

```
set.seed(101)
y <- rnorm(100)
x <- runif(100)
f <- gl(10,10)
z <- data.frame(zz1=rnorm(100),zz2=rnorm(100)) ## equivalent to your 'data'
```

Combine all the data into a single data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(x,y,f,z)
```

Construct base model: nothing extra

```
m0 <- lme(y~x,random=~1|f,data=d)
```

Put together a formula that looks like `~ . + NEWNAME`, and use it to update the model:

```
n <- names(z)[1]
m1 <- update(m0,reformulate(c(".",n),response="."))
```

Apply this approach to all of the columns (genes)

```
fitList <- lapply(names(z),
                  function(n) update(m0,reformulate(c(".",n),response=".")))
```

I'm concerned about a couple of other things with your model specification:

- `is.ill` sounds like a binary response; have you considered fitting a generalized linear mixed model (with `glmer` from the `lme4` package)?
- in general having the same variable (`pulse` in this case) included in the model as both a fixed effect and a grouping variable is a bad idea, although there is an exception where (1) the variable is continuous and (2) there are repeated measurements for many observed values of the variable (in this case the fixed effect will explain linear trend and the random effect will explain random variation around the line of *groups* of observations).

Comment: Ben Bolker's suggestion of putting all the data into one data.frame also solved my problem when I was doing nls(). I knew my variables were the correct class but couldn't get the regression to work until I took the columns I needed out of a large data.frame and put them into a new one.